# Read Remote file using desktop application C#

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming, desktop-application, remote-server

I am trying to develop a desktop  application in c# from which we can access and modify files in a remote server.

As a first stage i tried `WNetAddConnection2` for connecting to the remote server, but it doesn't seems to work showing:

> Network path not found.

Also is it possible to update the file contents using remote access from client machine.
Here what i tried

```
private void ConnectToShare(string remoteFilePath, string username, string password)
     {
         NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE
         {
             dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
             lpRemoteName = remoteFilePath
         };
         int result = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);

          if (result != NO_ERROR)
          {
              throw new Win32Exception(result);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try pasting the value from `remoteFilePath` into _Windows Explorer_ to see what happens?

Comment: Yes I have.But showing Network path error.

Comment: _"Yes I have.But showing Network path error"_ - If it doesn't work from Windows Explorer, it won't work from your app.  There is obviously a problem with your path